# Run expensive code only once, on triggering multiple changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few input objects.

I have a code that does something when they are changed -

```
for (var i=0; i<100; ++i)
  my_inputs[i].on('change', function() {
    showValue($(this).val());  // Display the value it changed to
    someExpensiveOperation();  // A common refresh for any change
  });
```

I want to reset all of them to 0.

```
for (var i=0; i<100; ++i) {
  my_inputs[i].val(0);
  my_inputs[i].change();  // Calls someExpensiveOperation 100 times!
}
```

What's a good way to redesign my code to prevent the refresh being called when I manually reset the values? Will promises/defferred help here?

Comment: "Will promises/defferred help here?" No. You can define a _general_ refresh function and call it once after the loop.

Comment: If you're doing `someExpensiveOperation` after *every* update to your array and it's already causing you problems, maybe you ought to be doing `someExpensiveOperation` a bit more judiciously.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debounce the calls to `someExpensiveOperation()`:

```
 var someExpensiveOperationDebouncing = 0;

 function debouncedSomeExpensiveOperation() {
     if (someExpensiveOperationDebouncing) {
         return;
     }

     // wait at least 1/4 second before calling someExpensiveOperation again
     ++someExpensiveOperationDebouncing;
     setTimeout(function () {
         --someExpensiveOperationDebouncing;
     }, 250); 

     someExpensiveOperation.apply(this, arguments);
 }
```

Also have a look at lodash's [`_.debounce(func, [wait], [options])`](https://lodash.com/docs#debounce).

Comment: This puts the responsibility on `debouncedSomeExpensiveOperation`, but if the requirement is to call `someExpensiveOperation` only after the preparation work is done (the loop...), this is dangerous

Comment: This actually works for me :) It nicely encapsulates the logic in one place.

Answer (score 2):

Just separate the special operation and the expensive common operation, and then when you reset the values, you can call the expensive common operation only at the end of the loop.

```
function specialOperation(input) {
    showValue($(this).val()); // Display the value it changed to
}
for (var i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    my_inputs[i].on('change', function() {
        specialOperation(my_inputs[i]);
        someExpensiveOperation(); // A common refresh for any change
    });
```

The reset code will then become:

```
for (var i=0; i < 100; ++i) {
    my_inputs[i].val(0);
    specialOperation(my_inputs[i]);
}
someExpensiveOperation();  // A common refresh for any change
```

Comment: So instead of calling the change(), I call the internal mechanisms separately. Nice solution :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Probably best to have a flag tested inside `someExpensiveOperation`:

```
function someExpensiveOperation() {
  if(skipExpensive) {
    return;
  }
  // real work below...
}
```

```
skipExpensive = true;
for (var i=0; i<100; ++i) {
  my_inputs[i].val(0);
  my_inputs[i].change();
}
skipExpensive = false;
someExpensiveOperation();
```

Comment: So create a flag to disable it if needed! Pretty smart - thanks.